# C# WPF PointCollection не обновляет UI

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

Необходимо сделать приложение, в котором по нажатию на кнопку к ней протягивалась бы ломанная линия, решил сделать это через Polyline

```
  <Polyline Grid.Row="1" IsHitTestVisible="False" Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="4" 
              Points="{Binding Source={StaticResource GKVM}, Path=Points,
              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

и привязать к коллекции PointCollection

```
  PointCollection points = new PointCollection();
    public PointCollection Points
    {
        get { return points; }
        set
        {
            points = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

и вроде всё хорошо, но вот проблема, если добавлять точку в конструкторе VM следующим образом:

```
    Point point = new Point()
        {
            X = 10,
            Y = 20
        };
        Points.Add(point);

        Point point2 = new Point()
        {
            X = 350,
            Y = 145
        };
        Points.Add(point2);
```

То линия прекрасно отображается в окне, а если делать тоже самое через команду, по нажатию на кнопку

```
   Command addPoint;
    public Command AddPoint
    {
        get
        {              
            return addPoint ??
           (addPoint = new Command(obj =>
            {
                Point point = new Point()
                {
                    X = MouseX,
                    Y = MouseY - 40
                };
                Points.Add(point);
            }));
        }
    }
```

То отображения линии не происходит, хотя в режиме отладки убедился, что точка добавляется в коллекцию, но почему-то именно в такой способ она не отображается, уже сутки голову ломаю.

Comment: PointCollection, очевидно, не реализует INotifyCollectionChanged.

Comment: Но почему же в случае с конструктором ВМ добавление происходит???

Comment: Потому что INotifyCollectionChanged «обслуживает» только обновление, а не первоначальную установку.

Comment: Так как же мне быть в таком случае?

Comment: ....`ObservableCollection`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вопрос не оставался открытым: измените тип `Points` с `PointCollection` на `ObservableCollection<Point>`. У вас получится просто

```
public ObservableCollection<Point> Points { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Point>();
```