# Есть ли альтернатива PointCollection которая реализует интерфейс INotifyCollectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Возникла такая проблема: необходимо задать параметры точек с помощью таблицы реализуемой на MVVM,однако PointCollection который требуется для Polygon не реализует этот интерфейс а другие коллекции не подходят. Может что то сталкивался или знает что делать.

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` относится к _свойствам_ объекта. Может, вы имеете в виду `INotifyCollectionChanged`?

Comment: Да верно я не тот интерфейс указал.

Comment: Чем `другие коллекции не подходят.`? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/755292/220553

Comment: В том что Polynom принимаем в качестве привязки только PointCollection а другие коллекции не работают(

Comment: Я понял как решить эту проблему. Я конвертировал значение и получил требуемый класс